# MLE of ratio of mean and sd

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I was given an iid random sample with size $n$ ~ $N\left(\mu,\sigma^2 \right)$

I found the **MLE** for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ seperately.

Then he asked me to find the MLE of $\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$.I stuck in here.I am thinking of using invariance property.I don't know how to do the next step.

Comment: I have checked the answer and the mle of mean and variance are correct.Then i write an equation X/(Y^0.5) substituting X=mle of mean, Y= mle of variance then i claimed that it is mle for μ/σ.I also need to find the expectation of this mle. I find it difficult to do the integration.So i think i am wrong.Can you give me some hint of how to handle this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Why don't you do that? The invariance property of the mle simplifies matters greatly and it is not something you necessarily find for other estimators, e.g. bayesian or method of moments estimators.

Comment: I have checked the answer and the mle of mean and variance are correct.Then i write an equation X/(Y^0.5) substituting X=mle of mean, Y= mle of variance then i claimed that it is mle for μ/σ.I also need to find the expectation of this mle. I find it difficult to do the integration.So i think i am wrong.Can you give me some hint of how to handle this question?

Comment: @CCKKLLGG Why don't you use the independence of $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$?